# Benchmarking Theano and CNTK with a simple matrix-vector product on the GPU

Tags: gpu, theano, benchmarking, cntk

I want to compare the performance of Theano and CNTK on a very simple task: matrix-vector product on the GPU. I am using Theano 0.9.0 and CNTK 2.0.

I want to measure the time consumed for the computation on the device only, excluding the time used for data transfer from host to device, or vice versa.

The result I got was something like this:
[figure (timings theano vs cntk)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQmZD.png)
(N is the number of repetitions. D, the size of the matrix, was set to 10000.)

Question 1:

It seems like the time used for some preparation (compiling the computational graph?) is included in the first execution of the mat-vec product in the CNTK case. 
Is there any way to split the preparation and the execution in CNTK, like it is in the Theano case?

Question 2:

I am used to Theano, but totally new at CNTK, so I am not quite sure if the CNTK code is equivalent to the Theano code. 
I am particularly not sure if the operation in the for loop of the CNTK code is really enclosed in the device, since prod.eval() returns a numpy.ndarray. Am I missing something?

Code used to measure the timings:

```
import numpy as np
import time

# theano
def test_matVecDot_theano(D, N):
    import theano
    import theano.tensor as T
    A_cpu = np.random.normal(size=[D,D]).astype(np.float32)
    x_cpu = np.random.normal(size=[D]).astype(np.float32)
    A_gpu = theano.shared(A_cpu)
    x_gpu = theano.shared(x_cpu)
    b_gpu = theano.shared(x_cpu)
    b_gpu_new = T.dot(A_gpu,x_gpu)
    fnc = theano.function(inputs=[], outputs=None, updates=[(b_gpu, b_gpu_new)], allow_input_downcast=True)
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        fnc()
    toc = time.time()
    print("time_theano:",toc-tic)

# cntk
def test_matVecDot_CNTK(D, N):
    import cntk as C
    A_cpu = np.random.normal(size=[D,D]).astype(np.float32)
    x_cpu = np.random.normal(size=[D,1]).astype(np.float32)
    A_c = C.Parameter(init=A_cpu, dtype=np.float32)
    x_c = C.Parameter(init=x_cpu, dtype=np.float32)
    b_c = C.Parameter(init=x_cpu, dtype=np.float32)
    prod = C.times(A_c, x_c)
    tic = time.time()
    for i in range(N):
        b_c.value = prod.eval() # is this operation enclosed in the device?
    toc = time.time()
    print("time_cntk:",toc-tic)
```

Comment: Why not using `nvprof` to measure GPU kernel execution time directly? Although I doubt there will be any big difference as they just call cuBLAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, the operation is not enclosed on the device. Here's what happens: When you call eval(), the call goes to C++ which does the operation on the device if possible. When coming out of C++, CNTK checks whether the value of `as_numpy` keyword argument, which by default is True. When `as_numpy` is True, the gpu buffer is eagerly copied to a NumPy array.

If you call prod.eval(as_numpy=False), then the call to `eval` will not convert the gpu buffer to a NumPy array. If you assign the result to a plain old variable, you can see that you get a CNTK Value object. However in your code you assign to the `.value` attribute of `b_c`. This assignment is handled by the setter of the `value` property (since this answer is getting a little too technical I'm including [this link](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#property) for the sake of other readers). CNTK does this assignment on the device, although it's hard to tell. This is because if you try to inspect `b_c.value` if you are calling the `.value` property getter which is going to give you a NumPy array. So it looks like the result is a NumPy array but this is just a consequence of using `b_c.value`. Any other variable would let you see it is a CNTK Value object. Again, all this applies to when you do `eval(as_numpy=False)`.

Furthermore, CNTK uses timestamps so the above evaluation happens only once on the GPU. All subsequent `N-1` calls to eval() will just return you the same value object (the conversion to Numpy will happen each time though, unless you specify `as_numpy=False`.

Finally, I don't expect to learn many meaningful lessons from this benchmark: both CNTK and Theano are calling the same CuDNN implementation, the advantages of CNTK are more around higher level things such as (a) comes with a high-level library (b) the user doesn't have to worry about the batch and sequence axes except for a few specialized operations (c) efficient recurrent networks (d) efficient i/o (e) easy distributed training.

And to answer your question about setup time: My understanding is if you just eval the function once, that will compile it. CNTK actually has two kinds of compilations: if you just `eval` the first time it will compile the forward pass. If you later do `function.grad` it will throw away the eval compilation and compile it again so that it can handle both the forward and backward pass.